# SetWindowsHookEx does not work in C# .net core?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, hook

I'm using the following code trying to get OS wide keyboard inputs with no luck:

```
using System;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class InterceptKeys

{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()

    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

        while(true)
            continue;
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())

        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }
    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine(vkCode);
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

}
```

HookCallback is simply not being called. I have a suspicion it's trying to listen only to a form which doesn't exist rather than running system wide.

Comment: What's the return value of the `SetWindowsHookEx`?

Comment: Why would you limit yourself to .NET Core when your application is windows specific anyway?

Comment: All of these functions return `IntPtr.Zero` or `false` on failure. You can use `throw new Win32Exception()` to convert an error return into a readable exception. Note that global hooks from managed code are rather tricky, to say the least (and even from unmanaged code -- the "remarks" section for `SetWindowsHookEx` is 8 paragraphs for a reason). That's before throwing .NET Core into the mix.

Comment: You need to run message loop in the thread that calls SetWindowsHookEx. In your code, replace endless loop `while(true)` with message loop.

Comment: @Alejandro It returns a number

Comment: @nvoigt I'm hoping to make this multiplatform in the future, having said that I'm happy to ditch .net core if I can get it working in full phat .net

Comment: @JeroenMostert Unfortunately I'm not getting errors...

Comment: @AlexF What's a message loop? I'm not very familiar with low level managed programming :(

Comment: So what's the value of `_hookID` and what error text do you get through `throw new Win32Exception()`?

Comment: @nvoigt 'Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in boris.dll: 'Unknown error (0xb1c0861)' - value is random numbers, last time it 6424422 but it can be other numbers too

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed5be22c-cef8-4615-a625-d05caf113afc/console-keyboard-hook-not-getting-called?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @AlexF a message loop was the solution, thanks for the links! If you could post it as an answer with a quick explanation I'd be happy to mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low-level Windows hooks internally use Windows messaging. The thread that calls `SetWindowsHookEx` must have the message loop in the end, which allows to call `HookCallback` function. In C++ message loop looks like this:

```
MSG msg;
BOOL result;

for (;;)
{
    result = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);

    if (result <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Find all required PInvoke definitions for `GetMessage`, `TranslateMessage`, `DispatchMessage` and `MSG`, translate this code to C# and place it instead of your endless loop `while(true)`. You can find all this stuff at PInvoke.Net, see also this Microsoft forum discussion:

Console keyboard hook not getting called

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed5be22c-cef8-4615-a625-d05caf113afc/console-keyboard-hook-not-getting-called?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0):

I'm obviously very late but just hoping I could help (if the OP haven't have yet the help he/she needed) so I'm posting my answer.

It says in the MSDN documentation that when you want to set a system-wide hook, you must give the hMod parameter a

> handle to the DLL containing the hook procedure pointed to by the lpfn
>   parameter

and

> If the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a
>   thread created by a different process, the lpfn parameter must point
>   to a hook procedure in a DLL

but, look at this:

> SetWindowsHookEx(2, kbdHookProc, GetModuleHandle("user32"), 0)

kbdHookProc is a function in my C# winforms application but the value I gave in the hMod parameter is the hinstance obtained by loading user32.dll via GetModuleHandle. I am using the keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD) to monitor locking of capslock, numlock and scroll lock keys. Don't ask me why I did that and would it work or why it works because I don't know but, yes, IT WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

For a full answer to this;

As Alex says, you'll need a message loop to process windows messages and call your hooks,

```cs
public class MessageLoop
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetMessage(out MSG lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin,
        uint wMsgFilterMax);
    
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool TranslateMessage([In] ref MSG lpMsg);
    
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr DispatchMessage([In] ref MSG lpmsg);
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MSG
    {
        IntPtr hwnd;
        uint message;
        UIntPtr wParam;
        IntPtr lParam;
        int time;
        POINT pt;
        int lPrivate;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Point(POINT p)
        {
            return new System.Drawing.Point(p.X, p.Y);
        }

        public static implicit operator POINT(System.Drawing.Point p)
        {
            return new POINT(p.X, p.Y);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"X: {X}, Y: {Y}";
        }
    }
    
    private Action InitialAction { get; }
    private Thread? Thread { get; set; }
    
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    public MessageLoop(Action initialAction)
    {
        InitialAction = initialAction;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        IsRunning = true;
        
        Thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            InitialAction.Invoke();
            
            while (IsRunning)
            {
                var result = GetMessage(out var message, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0);

                if (result <= 0)
                {
                    Stop();
                    
                    continue;
                }

                TranslateMessage(ref message);
                DispatchMessage(ref message);
            }
        });
        
        Thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        IsRunning = false;
    }
}
```

I use a separate thread here to avoid blocking the main thread.

The `InterceptKeys` class as shown in the question needs no modification;

```cs
class InterceptKeys
{
    // ...

    public static void Main()
    {
        var loop = new MessageLoop(() => {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        });
        
        loop.Start();

        while (Console.ReadKey(true) != ConsoleKey.X) // For exemplary purposes
        {
            continue;
        }

        loop.Stop();
    }

    // ...
}
```